# Mac Thunderbird to Mac Gmail a simple solution?

Tags: email, thunderbird, gmail, imap

I've been using Thunderbird on my Macs for years and only recently had to switch to Gmail, because Verizon will no longer have e-mail service.

- I've been learning how to use Gmail and discovered that "Folders" in Thunderbird relates pretty directly to "Labels" in Gmail.
- It appears that Thunderbird using Pop3 protocols may not play well with Gmail's Imap system!!

I have a fairly extensive Folder and subfolder setup in Thunderbird that I'd like to convert to the Gmail Label system, but all the help sites get very technical in any process that will even approach moving my folders into corresponding "Labels" in Gmail!

Does anyone have a "Thunderbird to Gmail For Dummies" solution to this question!?? Otherwise I guess I'll just reconstruct what I had in Thunderbird SLOWLY in Gmail!!!
If you have a solution I would be forever in your debt!!!  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

There are various methods to convert Thunderbird to Gmail on MAC. One of the methods is Synchronization of Thunderbird with Gmail.You must read how to do it here https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-gmail
Good luck..!